# How do I transfer data to a different activity with a broadcast receiver in between?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-activity

I am trying to transfer a string value from one intent to the next activity. But in the middle there is a Broadcast receiver. I cannot figure out how to transferred the value with the Broadcast receiver in between...

Comment: What do you mean by "in the middle" and "in between"?

Comment: I created a dialer and when the reciever detect the outgoing call it sends to new activity. I want to transfer the number that was sent to the new activity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`sendBroadcast()` to broadcast an intent with a String extra in it.

How the intent (or its extras) gets from your BroadcastReceiver to the code that needs it depends on how you organize your receiver; if you make it a dynamically registered receiver and it's defined within the class that actually needs the data, it gets pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the intent through start activity.
you can use the below code snippet

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("your code package", "your activity where it need to go");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.setType("your String message");
        context.startActivity(i);
```